# Преобразование символов cp1251 -> utf-8 -> cp1251

Tags: c++, utf-8, boost, cp1251, utf

Работаю под MS VS 2017, VC++ + boost, Win-7. Задача такая: читаем из консоли (или другого места с настройкой кодировки cp1251), далее надо преобразовать в UTF-8, записать в файл, прочитать из файла UTF-8, преобразовать в 1251 и выдать текст (в данном коде вывод на консоль). Код:

```
system("chcp 1251");

std::string temp;
std::cin >> temp;

boost::locale::generator generator;
std::locale locale = generator.generate("ru-RU.cp1251");

std::string s = boost::locale::conv::to_utf < char > (temp, locale);

std::fstream fout;
fout.open("file.txt", std::ios::out);
fout << s;
fout.close();

std::string result;

std::fstream fin;
fin.open("file.txt", std::ios::in);
std::getline(fin, result);
fin.close();

std::cout << boost::locale::conv::from_utf < char >(result, locale) << std::endl;
```

Вопросы такие:

1. Какие конкретно действия выполняют `generator` и его `generate`?
2. `to_utf` - преобразовывает в UTF-8 или какой-то еще? В документации написано просто UTF. Правильно ли я написал обратное преобразование `from_utf`? Там те же аргументы?
3. Я смог использовать только id ru-RU.cp1251. Для консоли не работает ru-RU.cp866, генерируется bad_cast. И пришлось добавить `system("chcp 1251");`
    Почему так?
4. Здесь достаточно использовать `std::string` и `char` или по какой-то причине может потребоваться wide-режим? Немного запутался, если я вот так жонглирую кодировками, то в какой ситуации может потребоваться wide?

Comment: 1. boost::locale::generator - класс-фабрика, порождающий локали, generator - его экземпляр, а generate - фабричный метод. Подробней читайте в книгах по паттернам проектирования.

Comment: 3. Судя по документации "ru_RU" должно быть через подчеркивание. Пробовали другие варианты названия кодировки, например "ru_RU.866" или "ru_RU.OEM"?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Другие варианты некоторые пробовал, OEM сейчас попробую. Про фабрику я понимаю, почему нельзя написать просто `std::locale locale{"ru-RU.cp1251"}`?

Comment: Единственное преимущество использования boost в данном случае в том, что generator умеет кэшировать ранее созданные локали. А полезно это только если вы в программе меняете их множество раз.

Comment: 3. попробуйте убрать system("chcp 1251"), создать локаль с пустым именем (дефолтную), и вывести имя созданной локали.

Comment: 4. `wide` здесь не нужен. UTF-8 использует для кодировки символов байтовые последовательности разной длины (коды 0-127 один байт, русские буквы - 2 байта, ну и побольше для некоторых экзотических символов). `wide` будет удобен, если потребуется работать с кодировкой UTF-16.